# Notation of maximization in pseudocode

Tags: geometry, notation

I'm working on the implementation of a simple algorithm. See this small excerpt:

[image]

*S* is a set of points from which I have to choose point *p*.

I am confused as how to find *p*. I know how to calculate the radius and angle mentioned for each point in *S*. I can find the point with the maximum *radius( before(p), p, after(p))*, and the same for the angle.

But what does it mean to maximize both, written as *maximizing (radius, angle)*.

Comment: Each $p$ has an associated triple $(r(p), a(p),n(p))$. These triples are sorted using the dictionary order.

Comment: @copper.hat, sorry, but what is _n(p)_? And does this mean I first sort on _r(p)_ and then on _a(p)_?

Comment: I am sorry, I missed a parenthesis, each $p$ is associated with a pair $(r(p), a(p))$. Then $(r_1,a_1) \le (r_2, a_2)$ **iff** $r_1 < r_2$ or ( $r_1=r_2$ **and** $a_1 \le a_2$ ).

Comment: The comparison for your sort must implement the above ordering.

Comment: @copper.hat, Ok excellent, that clears it all up. If you post as an answer I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be able to help!